# JOLT Transform - Nested Json to Flat Json with multiple rows

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am attempting to write a Jolt transformation specification to convert nested JSON to flat JSON with rows. The goal is to create a single spec that can handle both Input Data 1 and Input Data 2.

Input Data 1

```json
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Name": "tets",
  "records": [
    {
      "aaa": "123",
      "test": [
        {
          "zzz": 987,
          "yyy": 123
        },
        {
          "zzz": 345,
          "yyy": 678
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Input Data 2

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "tets",
    "records": [
      {
        "aaa": "123",
        "test": [
          {
            "zzz": 987,
            "yyy": 123
          },
          {
            "zzz": 345,
            "yyy": 678
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "1234",
    "Name": "tets2",
    "records": [
      {
        "aaa": "123",
        "test": [
          {
            "zzz": 987,
            "yyy": 123
          },
          {
            "zzz": 345,
            "yyy": 678
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "aaa": "12345",
        "test": [
          {
            "zzz": 456,
            "yyy": 567
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want the output for input 1

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "tets",
    "records.aaa": "123",
    "records.test.zzz": 987,
    "records.test.yyy": 123
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "tets",
    "records.aaa": "123",
    "records.test.zzz": 345,
    "records.test.yyy": 678
  }
]
```

And for input 2, the output should be in the below format

```json
[
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "tets",
    "records.aaa": "123",
    "records.test.zzz": 987,
    "records.test.yyy": 123
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Name": "tets",
    "records.aaa": "123",
    "records.test.zzz": 345,
    "records.test.yyy": 678
  },
  {
    "Id": "1234",
    "Name": "tets2",
    "records.aaa": "123",
    "records.test.zzz": 987,
    "records.test.yyy": 123
  },
  {
    "Id": "1234",
    "Name": "tets2",
    "records.aaa": "123",
    "records.test.zzz": 345,
    "records.test.yyy": 678
  },
  {
    "Id": "1234",
    "Name": "tets2",
    "records.aaa": "12345",
    "records.test.zzz": 456,
    "records.test.yyy": 567
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "temp"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "temp": "MANY"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "records": {
            "*": {
              "test": {
                "*": {
                  "@(5,[&4].Id)": "[&5][&3][&1].Id",
                  "@(5,[&4].Name)": "[&5][&3][&1].Name",
                  "@(2,aaa)": "[&5][&3][&1].&4\\.aaa",
                  "*": "[&5][&3][&1].&4\\.&2\\.&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**NOTE:** If you have more nested values, you should sure about how many they are, then JOLT can help you achieve your desired output. Otherwise, you can find another way with other tools or libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following spec

```json
[
  { // prepare to combine the two types of inputs 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "type1",
        "Id": "input1"
      },
      "@": "type2[]", // convert to array this one as well by nesting within square breackets
      "Id": "input2"
    }
  },
  { // distinguish and pick the presented input to be processed within the next specs
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "input1?": "@1,type1", // check the existence of the respective attributes by using ? at the end
      "input2?": "@1,type2"
    }
  },
  { // determine the independent objects of the reformed array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "input*": {
        "*": {
          "records": {
            "*": {
              "test": {
                "*": {
                  "@4,Id": "&5\\.&3\\.&1.Id",
                  "@4,Name": "&5\\.&3\\.&1.Name",
                  "@2,aaa": "&5\\.&3\\.&1.&4\\.aaa",
                  "*": "&5\\.&3\\.&1.&4\\.&2\\.&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: It is working for this type of JSON only. But it is not all types of nested JSON. I need a generic jolt spec which able to handle all level of nested json.

{"Id":"123","Name":"tets","records":[{"aaa":"123","test":[{"zzz":987,"yyy":123,"tst":[{"asd":12},{"asd":1234}]},{"zzz":345,"yyy":678,"tst":[{"asd":1278}]}]}]}